# Plotly Dash Gantt chart with Plotly express

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a Gantt chart that will show the production schedule in the shop floor. I want to see in the timeline on which station each of the products is proceeding with its start, finish times, name of the product and which worker is working on this product. I have created a data frame with 5 columns and 71 rows. The amount of rows might be bigger, but the amount of columns is constant. Is the Gantt chart created with Plotly Express timeline (px.timeline) supported in Dash? In my case the chart in Dash is represented incorrectly. The bars that show different processes are merged. Charts are represented correctly when I try to show it in kernel or just as a separated html page without Dash. Moreover, the timelines in the charts differ as well.
I tried to set the size of the chart and set the configuration to autosizable, but it didn’t help. The chart didn’t change. I tried to use the example code from Plotly documentation (https://plotly.com/python/gantt/#use-a-pandas-dataframe), and it worked fine. Do you have any idea how it can be resolved?

Thank you in advance!

Data Frame

```
               Finish    Location               Start    Worker
0   2021-04-06 0:01:40   STATION-1  2021-04-06 0:00:00  WORKER-1
1   2021-04-06 0:00:40   STATION-6  2021-04-06 0:00:30  WORKER-3
2   2021-04-06 0:11:40   STATION-2  2021-04-06 0:01:40  WORKER-2
3   2021-04-06 0:04:00   STATION-5  2021-04-06 0:02:20  WORKER-1
4   2021-04-06 0:06:20   STATION-1  2021-04-06 0:04:40  WORKER-1
5   2021-04-06 0:10:00   STATION-1  2021-04-06 0:08:20  WORKER-3
6   2021-04-06 0:22:00   STATION-3  2021-04-06 0:10:00  WORKER-1
7   2021-04-06 0:20:00   STATION-2  2021-04-06 0:11:40  WORKER-3
8   2021-04-06 0:13:50   STATION-6  2021-04-06 0:13:40  WORKER-2
9   2021-04-06 0:22:20   STATION-7  2021-04-06 0:14:00  WORKER-2
10  2021-04-06 0:25:20   STATION-4  2021-04-06 0:20:20  WORKER-3
...
```

Chart code

```py
# Gantt chart for workers
events_workers.sort_values(by=['Worker'],ascending=True, inplace=True)
# events_workers.sort_values('location_num')
fig_workers = px.timeline(events_workers, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Location", color="Worker", title="Workers schedule")
fig_workers.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig_workers.update_yaxes(type='category')
fig_workers.update_yaxes(categoryorder='array')
fig_workers.update_yaxes(categoryarray=df_mapping)
fig_workers.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H:%M:%S")
fig_workers.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showline=True, showgrid=True, showticklabels=True, ticks='outside'),
                 yaxis=dict(showline=True, showgrid=True, showticklabels=True, ticks='outside'))
fig_workers.show()
```

```py
import dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app=JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout=html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
            id='gantt-workers',
            figure=fig_workers,
    #       style={'width': '2000px', 'height':'2000px'},
    #       config={'autosizable':True}
        ),    

])

app.run_server(mode="jupyterlab", port=8002)
```

[Gantt chart in Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVXzx.png)

[Gantt chart in Jupyter Notebook kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya5tn.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with the dash code and the non dash code? Plotly express is compatible with Dash

Comment: @DevinBurke thank you for your comment. I added the code for non dash and dash in the question. In Dash I call the chart created in non Dash code.

Comment: Does Plotly Dash have limitations on the size of the data that can be represented with the Gantt chart?

Comment: Well everything is going to have *a* limit.